# JUnit dependency injection with Spring, MongoDB, and Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, junit5, reactor

I am a Java developer who is dipping his toes into Spring and Spring WebFlux by writing a REST API. I typically do TDD and when trying to write some JUnit test cases to test MongoDB queries I am running into some issues.

Example Repository:

```
@Repository
interface XReactiveRepository: ReactiveMongoRepository<X, String>
```

The Java equivalent:

```
@Repository
public interface XReactiveRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<X, String> { }
```

In Java I can use @Autowired to inject this dependency into the Unit test like so:

```
@Autowired
private XReactiveRepository repository
```

However I cannot do that directly in Kotlin

```
@Autowired
private repository: XReactiveRepository
```

This results in a compilation issue stating that it must be initialized or declared abstract. I have tried dependency injection via constructor but that also does not work. Any Kotlin/Spring devs know how to properly inject a repository into a JUnit5 test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the compilation issue means is that your `@Autowired` fields should be `lateinit var`.

However, Spring recommends using constructor injection over field injection.

Constructor injection should also work if you are using `@Autowired`, i.e.

```
class YourTestClass(@Autowired private val repository: XReactiveRepository)
```

By default Spring does not autowire test class constructors, unless you use the `@TestConstructor` annotation or change the `spring.test.constructor.autowire.mode` system property to `all`.

You can find this all from [Spring Framework Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html).

Comment: Thanks Arho! I tried passing it in through the constructor but that didn't work because I didn't annotate it with @Autowired. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Arho. I tried to google why need to @Autowired annotation in the TestClass and came to understand in your answer. Thank you ~